# Creating Custom Column in SharePoint 2010 with WSP Builder Project

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, wspbuilder

how can create Custom Column Field Type with Additional Functionalities in SharePoint 2010 of WSPBuilder Project?

Can I get the Sample Code to achieve this?